# What to use instead of regionMonitoringAvailable which is deprecated in iOS 7?

Tags: ios, ios7, deprecated, clregion

regionMonitoringAvailable is deprecated in iOS 7.  What are we supposed to use instead?

Comment: Looks like `isMonitoringAvailableForClass:`. See [Determining the Availability of Region Monitoring](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/RegionMonitoring/RegionMonitoring.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH9-SW3) in the Location and Maps Programming Guide.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The header file for `CLLocationManager` states that you should now use `[CLLocationManager isMonitoringAvailableForClass:]`:

> Determines whether the device supports monitoring for the specified type of region. If `NO`, all attempts to monitor the specified type of region will fail.

You pass in the class of `CLRegion` you wish to monitor. For example:

```
[CLLocationManager isMonitoringAvailableForClass:[CLBeaconRegion class]];
```

Edit: As @anna mentions above, this is also discussed in the [Location and Maps Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/RegionMonitoring/RegionMonitoring.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH9-SW3).

Apple usually post information about alternatives to deprecated methods, but unfortunately the documentation, headers, and other programming guides are sometimes out of sync with one another.